# Как правильно пишется уменьшительно-ласкательное от слова "пуговица"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать - пуговИчка и пуговЕчка?
И почему? Есть ли какое-то правило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прежде чем написать сомнительную гласную, следует понять, в какой части слова она находится и какому правилу подчиняется ее написание. В слове «пуговичка» ошибку часто делают, заменяя гласную И на Е. Попробуем разобраться, как писать правильно, объясняя свой выбор.

**Правильное написание**

Единственно верным вариантом написания слова в русском языке будет «пугов**и**чка» (гласная И в третьем слоге).

**Правило написания**

Чтобы понять, какое правило мы можем применить в данном случае, нужно произвести морфемный разбор слова:

1. Слово «пуговичка» образовалось от «пуговица», следовательно, выделяем суффикс -К-.
2. «Пуговица» – слово со связанным корнем, то есть без суффикса оно не может употребляться. Но один суффикс мы можем заменить на другой – «пуговка». Следовательно, в слове «пуговица» выделяем суффикс -ИЦ-.
   Орфограмма, которая нам интересна, находится в суффиксе.

Суффиксы -ИЧ- + -К- пишутся в существительных женского рода, образованных от существительных с суффиксом -ИЦ-. В остальных случаях пишется суффикс -ЕЧК-.

**Примеры предложений**

*У Шурки одна пуговичка на пальте уже не застёгивается – вот!* Иван Комлев «Ковыль»

*У мальчика оторвалась маленькая пуговичка, через минуту у дядечки из кармана выпала булка.* Дмитрий Болотов «Слоны и песок»

*Она носила пуговички то в виде браслета, то на пальце вместо колечка.* Гаяз Исхаки «Нищенка»

[Как правильно пишется «пуговичка»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/pugovichka)

Comment: В слове "пуговичка" нет суффикса ИЧК, а есть сочетание ИЧ в основе + суффикс К. Ударный суффикс ИЧК со значением лица женского пола встречается только в разговорной речи: математика – математичка.  (В грамматике желательно использовать точную терминологию.)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы - внёс изменения в ответ

Comment: Вы цитируете текст источника, а сейчас изменили его. Так низя.

Comment: Убрал цитирование

Comment: Но по сути у вас все ответы состоят из цитат с одного сайта, находящегося на стадии становления. Такое ощущение, что Вы его тестируете вместе с участником *Stasss*. :))

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Совсем "закритиковали" нового участника)) Здесь бы надо  предложить образцовый ответ, а у меня нерешенная проблема с суффиксом ИЦ. На мой вопрос не хотите ответить? Нужно ли выделять суффикс ИЦ в слове "пуговица"? Все ведь выделяют, а в словарях как?

Comment: @Sharon Не, ну правда, надо же и меру знать – так явно клепать вопросы (на которые намного проще найти ответ в поисковике, чем задать здесь) и ответы из одного пока сомнительного источника. //  А по суффиксам мне всё равно, какой там. Тёмный лес...

Comment: Вы правы, конечно. Ответы мне тоже не особо нравятся, да и формализм в них просто зашкаливает.  Составлены по принципу: учите, дети, правила.

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос, я нарушил какие-то правила? При регистрации было указано, что этот сайт для вопросов и ответов, а не для пустых обсуждений.

Comment: А если вам поставят минус за ответ, то вы будете обсуждать почему. Мы обсуждаем качество вашего ответа, а такие обсуждения  вряд ли следует считать пустыми. Вы утверждаете, что в слове пуговица суффикс ИЦ? Это нужно доказать по словообразовательным словарям. Вы можете доказать?  Это производное или непроизводное слово?

Comment: Да, это слово производное, и оно произошло от др.-рус. "пугъвъ" - подробнее я ответил в вашем вопросе